# ambiguous reference error for member variable 'name'

Tags: c++

I have declared a variable `name` within my `people` class which is producing an ambiguity error. I tried renaming the `name` variable, avoided using `using namespace std`, imported the required libraries, replaced character array with string type but it throws same error all the time. I referred to other posts on Stack Overflow but I could not find the solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>


class people{
    public:
    char name[20];
};

class staff : public people {
    public:
    int i = 3; 
};

class manager : public people {
    public:
    int j = 8;
};

class lecturer : public manager, public staff {
    public:
    void set(char* a) {
        strcpy(name, a);
    }
    void get(){
        std::cout << "Lecturer name: " << name << std::endl << "Number of managers: " << j << std::endl << "Number of staff: " << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    lecturer ob;
    ob.i = 1;
    ob.j = 6;
    ob.set("aaa bbb");
    ob.get();
    return 0;
}
```

and the error message is

```
main.cpp:24:16: error: reference to ‘name’ is ambiguous
     strcpy(name, a);
```

Comment: Do you mean `manager::name` or `staff::name`?

Comment: Error is with `people::name`

Comment: No, the problem is that you have *two* `name` variables, one from each base class (`staff` and `manager`). You have to explicitly pick one of them.

Comment: Oh alright. `name` got inherited twice for lecturer class. Thanks for resolving the issue.

Comment: This problem is sometimes called the Dreaded Diamond.

Comment: In this case it seems clear that `people` (which should be named `person`) should be a virtual base.  `lecturer` is one `people`, not two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know which member 'name' should use in the strcpy function since lecturer inherits from 2 classes which are manager and staff (both have member 'name'), so to tell the compiler who's name should use, to assign manager's name, you can use:

```cpp
strcpy(manager::name, a);
```

and for staff's name:

```cpp
strcpy(staff::name, a);
```